# Differential Equations: From Calculus to Dynamical Systems by Virginia W. Noonburg for self-study

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I have a background in undergraduate-level calculus, multivariable calculus, real analysis, linear algebra and abstract algebra, and I'm looking for a differential equations (ODEs, PDEs) book for self-study.

Many classic books are often cited as dated and lacking in modern approaches, such as numerical methods, for example Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes by George F. Simmons. I recently came across Differential Equations: From Calculus to Dynamical Systems by Virginia W. Noonburg, which has a very good [review](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/ordinary-differential-equations), but limited feedback online. Besides, looking at the book's samples, it seems a bit too concise and dry, and might not be suitable for self-study.

I am looking for opinions about this book, other recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Use either _'Introduction to Partial Differential Equations'_ by Olver, _'Partial DIfferential Equations'_ by Strauss or _'An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations'_ by Pinchover & Rubenstein for PDEs.

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend any ODE textbooks as well?

Comment: _'Differential Equations; Theory, Technique, and Practice'_ by Simmons or _'Advanced Engineering Mathematics'_ by Kreyszig (you only really need the first six chapters of Kreyszig). Both have lots of examples and practice questions, though you won't get a huge amount of theoretical understanding from either book. For that you really need a book on dynamical systems but that is too advanced for someone learning ODEs.

Comment: @Gonçalo I absolutely love Strogatz, but according to the MAA review, the book doesn’t seem suitable for the first course